# Guide: Full screen fixed layout webpage (header, search bar, content, event list and footer)

Tags: html, css, structure, flexbox

The purpose is to make whole screen size web page with header, search/navigation bar, content, event list and footer using flex.

[image: View of web page that wanted.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution and example. [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46p6un4w/8/)

1) Make flex with column direction.

[image: Column direction flex]

Basic structure HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="left">
   <!-- Here comes button, later in document -->
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Page branch
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <!-- Here comes dropdown, which is later in document -->
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <nav>Searchbar etc.</nav>
  <section class="content">Main content</section>
  <aside>Event list</aside>
</div>
<footer>Copyright footer etc.</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .title {
  flex: 0;
  /* Keep branch in same line if has many words */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

header .left, header .right  {
  flex: 1;
}

header .right  {
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: thistle;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}
```

[image: Inserting cells in header and container]

CSS:

```
aside, nav {
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

aside {
  background-color: khaki;
}
```

Button HTML append (inside left class):

```
<button class="button button-green">Button</button>
```

Dropdown HTML append (inside right class):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-title">Dropdown
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li>Menu item 1</li>
      <li>Menu item 2</li>
      <li>Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for button and dropdown:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  z-index: 5;
}

.dropdown-title:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline-style:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.button-green {
  border: 1px solid #aea;
  background-color: #bfb;
}

.button-green:hover {
  background-color: #dfd;
}
```

**All together**

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="left">
   <button class="button button-green">Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Page branch
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-title">Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li>Menu item 1</li>
          <li>Menu item 2</li>
          <li>Menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <nav>Searchbar etc.</nav>
  <section class="content">Main content</section>
  <aside>Event list</aside>
</div>
<footer>Copyright footer etc.</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .title {
  flex: 0;
  /* Keep branch in same line if has many words */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

header .left, header .right  {
  flex: 1;
}

header .right  {
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.dropdown-title:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline-style:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.button-green {
  border: 1px solid #aea;
  background-color: #bfb;
}

.button-green:hover {
  background-color: #dfd;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav, aside {
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

aside {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: thistle;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}
```

**Bonus**

In event list you might need scrollable list without messing current view.

HTML (set this inside aside -element):

```
<div class="scrollable-list"></div>
```

CSS:

```
aside {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollable-list {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Tell me if there is anything to improve, please.